# Building meta-virtualization layer in yocto:thud

Tags: docker, embedded-linux, yocto, lxc

I want to install docker to my yocto project. I have put meta-virtualization into bblayers and add following into local.conf.

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " virtualization"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " docker"
```

But now the build will have the "cannot find -lgcc_s" error, does anyone have relevant experience?

My yocto project version is thud. Following is the error log:

```
ERROR: runc-docker-1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: runc-docker-1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/temp/log.do_compile.639)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/temp/log.do_compile.639
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 16 BUILDTAGS=${PACKAGECONFIG_CONFARGS} GO=aarch64-poky-linux-go static
| CGO_ENABLED=1 aarch64-poky-linux-go build  -tags " netgo osusergo static_build" -installsuffix netgo -ldflags "-w -extldflags -static -X main.gitCommit="425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f-dirty" -X main.version=1.0.0-rc8 " -o runc .
| # _/yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/git/src/import
| /yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/lib/aarch64-poky-linux/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running aarch64-poky-linux-clang failed: exit status 1
| /yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-poky-linux/aarch64-poky-linux-ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
| clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
|
| Makefile:43: recipe for target 'static' failed
| make: *** [static] Error 2
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /yocto/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/runc-docker/1.0.0-rc8+gitAUTOINC+425e105d5a-r0/temp/log.do_compile.639)
```

Comment: I see you're using `clang` instead of `gcc`. Might it be the source of the problem?